# Java run switch case methods with List of items

Tags: java, foreach, switch-statement

I need to simplify my methods I need to run this method for all weekdays:

```
 if (!getAbsenceSo().equals("-")) {
        switch (getAbsenceSo()){
            case "uabgelehnt": setAbsenceSo("-"); break;
            case "urlaubbeantragt": setAbsenceSo("-"); break;
            case "urlaubgenehmigt": setAbsenceSo("Urlaub"); setArbeitMinutenSo((int)(wochenarbeitstunden*60/5)); break;
            case "sonderurlaub":  setAbsenceSo("Sonderurlaub"); setArbeitMinutenSo((int)(wochenarbeitstunden*60/5)); break;
            case "ueabsetzer": setAbsenceSo("Ü-Absetzer"); break;
            case "krank": setAbsenceSo("Krank"); setArbeitMinutenSo((int)(wochenarbeitstunden*60/5)); break;
            case "kindkrank": setAbsenceSo("Kindkrank"); setArbeitMinutenSo((int)(wochenarbeitstunden*60/5)); break;
            case "fbschule": setAbsenceSo("FB/Schule"); setArbeitMinutenSo((int)(wochenarbeitstunden*60/5)); break;
            case "kurzarbeit": setAbsenceSo("Kurzarbeit"); setArbeitMinutenSo((int)(wochenarbeitstunden*60/5)); break;
            case "unentschuldigt": setAbsenceSo("Unentschuldigt");  break;
        }
    }
```

so the next code snippet would look like this:

```
 if (!getAbsenceMo().equals("-")) {
    switch (getAbsenceMo()){
        case "uabgelehnt": setAbsenceMo("-"); break; and so on...
```

is there a way that I can use to prevent duplicate code?

I have not really much knowledge about Java - can you give me a hint?
That I can call a method within the object put together from a string.
e.g. how can I call  "setAbsense"+item("-"); ??? Or better how should this be done??? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to dynamically construct a method call. Instead, rethink your design. You've code that needs to be performed for multiple instances of the same type (same data, same methods). This already indicates: use a class. Every instance (Mo, Tu, ...) will have the same information, but you can manipulate it on that very instance itself.

Quick example to get you going:

```java
public class App {
    static class Absence {
        private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
        private String reason;
        private int arbeitMinuten;

        public Absence(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, String reason) {
            this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
            this.reason = reason;
        }

        public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
            return dayOfWeek;
        }

        public void setDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
            this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
        }

        public String getReason() {
            return reason;
        }

        public void setReason(String reason) {
            this.reason = reason;
        }

        public int getArbeitMinuten() {
            return arbeitMinuten;
        }

        public void setArbeitMinuten(int arbeitMinuten) {
            this.arbeitMinuten = arbeitMinuten;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int wochenarbeitstunden = 40;

        List<Absence> absenceList;
        // Build from your Datasource
        absenceList = List.of(new Absence(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, "uabgelehnt"), new Absence(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, "Krank"), new Absence(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, "Kurzarbeit"));

        for (Absence absence : absenceList) {
            switch (absence.getReason()) {
                case "uabgelehnt" -> absence.setReason("-");
                case "urlaubbeantragt" -> absence.setReason("-");
                case "urlaubgenehmigt" -> {
                    absence.setReason("Urlaub");
                    absence.setArbeitMinuten(wochenarbeitstunden * 60 / 5);
                }
                case "sonderurlaub" -> {
                    absence.setReason("Sonderurlaub");
                    absence.setArbeitMinuten(wochenarbeitstunden * 60 / 5);
                }
                case "ueabsetzer" -> absence.setReason("Ü-Absetzer");
                case "krank" -> {
                    absence.setReason("Krank");
                    absence.setArbeitMinuten(wochenarbeitstunden * 60 / 5);
                }
                case "kindkrank" -> {
                    absence.setReason("Kindkrank");
                    absence.setArbeitMinuten(wochenarbeitstunden * 60 / 5);
                }
                case "fbschule" -> {
                    absence.setReason("FB/Schule");
                    absence.setArbeitMinuten(wochenarbeitstunden * 60 / 5);
                }
                case "kurzarbeit" -> {
                    absence.setReason("Kurzarbeit");
                    absence.setArbeitMinuten(wochenarbeitstunden * 60 / 5);
                }
                case "unentschuldigt" -> absence.setReason("Unentschuldigt");
                default -> {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Peter, thanks for your reply. Understood and made it as u suggested ... for many other things also! Thanks for putting me in the right direction and givin me a really nice example!! Thank you!